# loop problems with string variable - error messages

Tags: loops

I am trying to make a loop for my dataset 'data1' to check and make a sum of the variable 'hours2015' in case the type of caregiver is the same (string variable= doctor, nurse, physical therapist, etc. So for each type of caregiver I would like to make the sum of total hours worked in 2015. I keep getting a syntax error messages. I can't seem to get the code right. Can anyone help me please? Thanks!

```
for(i in 1:133) {
    totalhours2015[i] <- data1$hours2015[i] + data1$hours2015[i+1]
    if {("data1$typecaregiver" [i] == "data1$typecaregiver" [i+1]) }
}
```

> Error: unexpected 'if' in:
>   "for(i in 1:133){ . 
>      totalhours2015[i] <- newrusthuizendata$uren2015[i] + newrusthuizendata$uren2015[i+1] if"
>   }
>   Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: Please tag this question with the language of your code.

Comment: It is okay. I solved it using the command ddply:                                                                                                                  ddply(data1, .(typecaregiver), summarize,
      sum2015= round(sum(hours2015), 2),
      sum2020= round(sum(hours2020), 2),
      sum2025= round(sum(hours2025), 2),
      sum2029= round(sum(hours2029), 2)
)